# Implicit cast through constructor with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, implicit

If I have these 2 constructors for `MyClass`:

```
MyClass(int n1);
MyClass(int n1, int n2);
```

and an overloaded (non-member) `operator+`:

```
MyClass operator+(MyClass m1, const MyClass& m2);
```

This enables me to write code like this:

```
MyClass m;
5 + m:
```

which I guess uses an implicit cast through the defined constructor, correct?

Is there any way to do this implicit cast with the constructor taking 2 arguments? With code looking something like this:

```
MyClass m;
{15, 8} + m:
```

?

Or maybe just do an explicit cast from {9, 4} to a `MyClass` object?

Comment: Do those who will have to maintain that code later (which might include you, BTW) a favor and make that constructor `explicit`. IME in the long run implicit conversions create more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: And putting MyClass(5) + m is always going to be clearer when someone reads this instead of having to go back to the class to wonder to which type it's converted, if any, or are you just adding an int to it.

Comment: sbi: sounds reasonable. How do I make the constructor explicit? Just add the keyword explicit in front of the declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, no.  The most succinct option is `MyClass(15,8) + m;`.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can construct in place:

```
MyClass m;
m + MyClass(15,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, but why do you need it to be implicit rather than explicit? If you're going to have to use the bracket notation anyway, it's not something that could be generated from a single variable, so I don't believe there's any downside to simply saying:

`myclass(15, 8) + m;`

This will generate it on the stack, and produce the same result as an implicit cast.